# ifconfig command only displays 'lo" interface but not others on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, interface

When I type ifconfig -a on my computer, all I see is the lo device, not eth0.

Also, when I type ifconfig interface, I get the following:

```
   interface: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

I am not sure what I should do now, as I am fairly new to linux/ubuntu.

I should also mention that I started out with 12.04, but I could not get wireless access. My ethernet cable was still working and I thought that going from 12.04 to 13.10 would get me the necessary drivers for the wireless. I started the update from 12.04 to 12.10 and planned to continue from there, but now I cannot get internet access anywhere. I basically dug myself in a bigger hole.

If it helps at all, I have an HP Envy Touchsmart. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ifcongif -a` and also see whether you're able to `ping localhost` whilst checking the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to download your wireless driver and install it.
Perhaps you was lacking a driver or the wireless driver may be disabled.